# Upgraded MongoDB and now shell dies with 'Illegal instruction'

Tags: mongodb

I was running MongoDB v2.0.4.
I installed v2.2.2 and restarted.

The mongod process is running fine. Client applications are connecting and functioning fine.
But the mongo shell bombs out.

```
$: ~ mongo localhost/da
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
connecting to: localhost/da
Illegal instruction
$: ~
```

My "install" process was to download & unpack the .tgz and simlink all the binaries in bin to /usr/local/bin.

Here's what I see in the log on start.

```
Thu Jan  3 16:14:54 Mongo DB : starting : pid = 7225 port = 27017 dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb/ master = 0 slave = 0  32-bit 

** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
**       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations for more

Thu Jan  3 16:14:54 db version v1.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Jan  3 16:14:54 git version: nogitversion
Thu Jan  3 16:14:54 sys info: Linux vernadsky 2.6.24-27-server #1 SMP Fri Mar 12 01:45:06 UTC 2010 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_40
Thu Jan  3 16:14:54 waiting for connections on port 27017
```

This is running on a 32bit machine w/ 4GB memory and dual core PIII 1.4GHz processor.

Thinking this could be the 'floating point exception' mentioned on the MongoDB downloads page I tried the legacy-static build. The result is the same.

UPDATE

I think the limitations of running on an older 32 bit system make running v2.2.2 too unstable. The 2GB limit is easily exceeded (as evidenced by 'Got signal: 4' errors) when doing a repair operation or checking journal files on start up.

I've decided to revert to v1.2.2 using the Ubuntu package manager.

References:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5639

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/gaAlONRvVSU/discussion

Comment: mongo.lock file?  You haven't changed the directory for storing the db files, correct?  If it is safe to remove the mongo.lock file I would attempt this first.

Comment: Stopped mongod, removed the mongod.lock, restarted mongod. I still get an illegal instruction on attempt to start the shell.

Comment: can you connect okay with 2.0 shell?  You should be able to run mongo executable from 2.0 distribution and point it at 2.2 server/mongod process.

Comment: Downloaded mongodb-linux-i686-2.0.8.tgz. I can run the mongo shell binary version 2.0.8 without the illegal instruction fault.

Comment: Please take a look at this link, it may be helpful in your case. 

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5639

Comment: it seems that mongodb 2.0.4 is the latest version without sse2 instructions and working on old x86 CPUs.

Comment: Rolling back to 2.0.4 worked for me too. I have detailed instructions on the steps to install the older version on Centos6 [here](http://turtle-philosophy.blogspot.com/2014/05/installing-mongodb-on-old-computer.html)

Comment: I wrote a detailed blog post about it [here](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/manjaro-compile-mongodb-from-source-and-install-it-manually/). The problem is that the binaries in the official repo are compiled using an instruction set that is not supported by old 32-bit CPUs. Solution: compile it from source and install manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Debian Squeeze 6.0.10 , an old 32-bit/i386 machine and with the 10gen distribution of the official mongodb instructions. On the instalation some problems with --configure of mongo-org-server and dependencies Trying to execute mongod "Illegal instruction" and

I had to purge the packages and install the 1.4.4 version through a simple `apt-get install mongodb`.